# passing Data in method that using generic ? it's that possible?

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to understand how to use **a method that uses generic**. And I want to create a generic method that can passing data to it. for example I want to create an array and add it with a variable in that **Method**. Byetheway I'm using **Java**

this is the code that i was Trying:

```
public class test {
static int d;
public static <E>  void AdditionArray (E[] arr, int var) {
    for (E element : arr) {
        d = element + var; //this is the big problem, I have no idea whether this is possible or not
        System.out.println(d);
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer [] arr1 = {1,4,5,7};

AdditionArray(arr1, 2);

    }

}
```

so one line of my codes definitely was wrong, but how can i do that ?

**a Method that using Generic and passing data to it** ?

Comment: Is it possible, yes. Does it make sense the way you're doing, not really - Java doesn't know what to do with `Object + Object`, it makes no sense from it's stand point. You could constraint the generic to `Number`, but even then, it doesn't make sense, because which "type" of number are you going a add (int, double, long, etc...)

Comment: What do you expect it do if you pass `new String[] { "foo" }`?

Comment: `this is the big problem, I have no idea whether this is possible or not` - did you try?

Comment: if it is possible ? how then ? how the way to make it ? @MadProgrammer

Comment: @shmoselit depends on what method is created ;)

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes I did, but it's doesn't  work hahaha

Answer (score 0):

If you want use generic to add array element consider extending Number type 
for instance:

```
public class Main {


    static int d;

    public static <E extends Number> void AdditionArray(E[] arr, int var) {
        for (E element : arr) {
            d = element.intValue() + var; //this is the big problem, I have no idea whether this is possible or not
            System.out.println(d);
        }

    }

  static String z;
   public static <E extends CharSequence> void AdditionArray2(E[] arr, int var) {
    for (E element : arr) {
        z += element.toString() + var; //this is the big problem, I have no idea whether this is possible or not
        System.out.println(z);
    }
}


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Integer[] arr1 = {1, 4, 5, 7};
       AdditionArray(arr1, 2);
       Double[] arr2 = {1.0, 4.0, 5.0, 7.0};
       AdditionArray(arr2, 2);

       String[] arr3 = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
       AdditionArray2(arr3, 2);


    }

}
```

Comment: oh mother of God, it works!!! how did you do that ?????? I don't even know that thing? from where I can know that ????????

Comment: Know put doubles into

Comment: Good point, having different number wrappers is good illustration of generic power.

Comment: how about <E extends CharSequence>, String in final so no luck here

Comment: Technically you can extend any class that is not final, usually a super class has certain shared behaviour that you may want to enforce vi generic usage

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with what a Lambda is, you can do this very succinctly in Java 8+ using lambdas.

Here's an example

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class GenericAddition {

public static <E> List<E> map(List<E> elements, Function<E, E> mapper) {
    List<E> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (E element : elements) {
        result.add(mapper.apply(element));
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String...args) {
    List<Integer> addedThree = map(Arrays.asList(5, 3, 4), (elem) -> elem + 3);
    System.out.println(addedThree);

    List<String> concatted = map(Arrays.asList("good", "guten", "baz"), (elem) -> elem + " day");
    System.out.println(concatted);
  }
}
```

This will print out:

```
[8, 6, 7]
[good day, guten day, baz day]
```

One catch is you have to use a List type because using E[] could be an array of primitives but your mapper function needs to take in objects (since type parameters must be of object types).  You could easily code around this restriction by adding a wrapper function that converts an array to a list, Java will be smart and perform auto-boxing for you in that case.

I personally think this is very readable and also very flexible since you can define any kind of logic for performing the mapping i.e. if I wanted to do something like add 5 if its odd, or *2 if its even, I can define my own lambda function for doing this. That way, I can get more complex behavior without having to write separate methods for each different type that I want.

If you are using an older Java version, you could do the same thing with anonymous inner classes that implement a particular interface.

Comment: yeah, you was right. But in this problem I just want to implementing and " know the power of ** Generics** " without any java Collections. that&amp;#39;s way I didn't use ** ArrayList ** .  And don't event know how I can use **lambda**

Comment: @jeryozdimitar, well this is still using generics.